# Nuget pack only including dependencies for some projects

Tags: nuget

I have a solution with two projects.

```
/Root/
      xxx.sln          
     /P1         
     /P2
```

I have defined a nuspec for both projects. P2 reference p1.

I have following build events for both projects:
del $(ProjectDir)*.nupkg
nuget pack $(ProjectPath) -IncludeReferencedProjects -OutputDirectory $(ProjectDir) -Prop Configuration=Release

P2 package do include dependencies to external nugets and p1.
p1 contains no dependencies, even though I have added many nuget packages to it.

What reasons can there be for not having any dependencies in the package?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was related to an old .sln file located in the folder also. This somehow triggered the behaviour. Removing that and everything worked as normal.