# NuGet pack for TFS Continuous Integration

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs, msbuild, nuget

I'm trying to make our TFS Build process to generate NuGet packages from our solution's projects. We aim to create a private package source, so all other internal products may download/update the framework using NuGet.

So far we've got the build process running (for a long time) and versioning our libraries, and the only thing that's left is to "**nuget pack**" all the projects.

---

**What i have tryed so far:**

1. nuget spec *.csproj, then nuget pack *.nuspec;
2. nuget spec *.dll, then nuget pack *.nuspec;
3. nuget pack *.csproj directly (no .nuspec file);

*All of them seem to work, but all of them seem to fail on the steps I actually need them to succeed.*

What I actually get from doing the mentioned steps:

1. **No** dependency¹ listed, **no** reference² listed;
2. **No** dependency¹ listed, **no** reference² listed, all dlls from the directory are packed on the same .nupkg (whitout using -IncludeReferencedProjects);
3. (The best so far) **Some** dependencies¹ listed, **no** reference² listed, only the actual project dll is inside the lib folder on the .nupkg.

¹: *By dependency I mean NuGet dependencies, the packages from NuGet*
²: *By reference I mean solution project references.*

---

Sample scenario:

Solution1.sln
  -- ProjectA
  -- ProjectB

ProjectA has a **Project Reference** to ProjectB. What I ***expect*** to happen on the .nuspec generated:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2011/08/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>ProjectA <- OK</id>
    <version>1.2.0.0 < - OK</version>
    <title>ProjectA <- OK</title>
    <authors>My Company <- OK</authors>
    <owners>My Company <- OK</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Description</description>
    <copyright>OK</copyright>
    <dependencies>
        <dependecy id="ProjectB" Version="1.2.0.0" /> <<<<<<---- NOT HAPPENING!
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

Some nuget dependencies are listed, but not all of them (even when they are inside the packages.config from the refeered project). For example: I have a project that dependends on 4 other NuGet packages, only 2 are listed as dependencies on the generated .nuspec file.

---

**Important information:**

- Every project has its own packages.config, the way NuGet builds it;
- The solution folder contains the packages folder, with all referenced packages;
- Already tryed Nugetter (XAML broken on VS 2012.3 and TFS 2012, cannot open it)
- Already tryed [this](http://ihadthisideaonce.com/2012/02/21/creating-packages-with-nuget-the-msbuild-way/), also does not include the dependencies and references properly;
- Solution package restore is turned **ON** (we need this to avoid storing the packages on TFS).

---

**What I need:**

- Automate the pack process to pack each csproj including all references and dependencies on the .nuspec file, so all of them will be properly loaded when installing it.

---

**Similar questions I've looked into:**

[NuGet: pack command is NOT including nuget dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9415919/nuget-pack-command-ist-not-including-nuget-dependencies)
[Nuget pack only including dependencies for some projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20542942/nuget-pack-only-including-dependencies-for-some-projects)
[Why doesn't nuget include the referenced project when packing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16190697/why-doesnt-nuget-include-the-referenced-project-when-packing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out to be a simple path problem. The references and dependencies were not being properly added because I was executing the command from a different working directory.

On top of that, the use of -IncludeReferencedProjects was necessary to properly add everything needed.

After that the build process using Powershell completed successfully and everything is worked as expected =)

Answer (score 1):

The pack command has an option for including project references that must be specified: http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/command-line-reference#Pack_Command_Options.

You'll need to target the csproj file, and I recommend creating a nuspec file manually.